# How to install ffmpeg-php Mac OS X leopard

Tags: php, macos, ffmpeg

Has anyone been able to install ffmpeg-php on osx?  i was able to install ffmpeg via mac ports.  ffmpeg-php wont install.

Problems:  cannot find shared directory because macports installs it to /opt/local/include/ and /opt/local/lib. ffmpeg-php looks in /usr/local/include/ffmpeg

phpize returns a whole bunch of warnings, not sure if this is a problem or not.

When i get all the headers/libraries in the right locations make is still throwing fits.

Has anyone actually done this?  or...

is there an alturnative to ffmpeg?  I want to be able to create pictures of video frames on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My "Formula" for ffmpeg-php is accepted.

Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and run:

```
brew install ffmpeg-php
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: When I tried it I had problems getting libmp3lame to be found: ERROR: libmp3lame not found

Comment: The formula always uses the latest version(svn trunk), but the current (revision 677) compiles just fine with ffmpeg 0.6.2. You might need to recompile ffmpeg (`brew install -f ffmpeg`) if it was already installed.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to compile it either although ffmpeg can still be useful without that extension. Here's a simple example that grabs a jpg every 5th secoond:

```
$ffmpeg = '/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg';
$vid = 'test.mpg';
$cmd = $ffmpeg.' -i '.$vid.' -r 0.2 -sameq -f image2 '.$vid.'.%03d.jpg';
exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the whole process of installing it on my OSX 10.6.2 using [these instructions](http://www.webrelatedstuff.com/blog/ffmpeg+and+ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-installation-on-mac-osx) as guidelines. What also helped me was getting the right files following instructions on [the site linked here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3srKCD3ok3w) (for the ffmpeg part) and the "simple" instructions under "Installation" from [ffmpeg-php site itself](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) for your actual question. All without any macport.

Can't say it was easy, but it's working just fine. It's a very long process that I just won't quote here. Hopefully it's suffice to say basically you need the most recent [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) then everything is a regular "./configure && make" process.

My **ffmpeg** configuration options were these: `--enable-libmp3lame --enable-shared --disable-mmx --arch=x86_64 --enable-libfaad --enable-gpl`

<sub>Just as a note, [this is how I found those links on google](http://www.google.com/search?num=30&hl=en&safe=off&tbs=qdr%3Ay&q=ffmpeg+php+mac&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) (all those search options are default for me, including the filtering by last year). Funny thing, the first result was this question, thus I'm here answering it. ;-)</sub>

Comment: One thing I'd like to see is XAMPP or some other kind of apache packaging coming with ffmpeg ready for mac already. Odd enough I couldn't find any.